# Solve $\log_2 \frac {18+x}x=2$ for $x$.

Tags: logarithms, proof-explanation

Solve the following for $x$:

$$\log_2 \frac {18+x}x=2$$

I am told that the equation implies $\frac {18 + x} x = 4$  (this is the step i didn't understand , Where did $\log_2$ go ?)

Given that, we get the solution.  $ x = 6 $  (This step is understood)

Comment: Do you mean $$\frac{\log_{2}(18+x)}{x}=2$$

Comment: Are you looking for (log_2 (18 + x))/x or log_2((18 + x)/x)?

Comment: This is hard to parse.  Do you mean $\frac {\log_2 (18+x)}x=2$? Or $\log_2 \frac {18+x}x=2$ ?  Or $\frac {\log_{10} (2)\times (18+x)}x=2$?  Or something else entirely?

Comment: In " log 2 " , 2 comes as a base to log

Comment: I gave three possible interpretations of your expression.  Does one of them happen to be right?  If so, which one?  If all three are incorrect, can you point us in a better direction?

Comment: By the solution I assume the denominator is inside the logarithm. Then it's easy, you just take a power of $2$ on both sides. Anyway, please use MathJax to write here.

Comment: Sorry , Yes Your second given option is right

Comment: Take a look at this link: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Note that $\log_2(b) = c \implies 2^c = b$. In general, $\log_{a}(b) = c \implies a^c = b$.

Comment: I have reformatted your post, please make sure I didn't introduce any errors.  As to the question, as others have remarked, $a=b\implies 2^a=2^b$, and you can use that to "remove" the $\log_2$.

Comment: \frac{\log_{2}(18+x)}{x}=2

Comment: thanks -lulu that was helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s pretty much the definition of a logarithm. For any exponential equation $a^b = c$, the logarithmic equation is in form $\log_a c = b$.
$a^b = c \implies\log_a c = b$

Answer (score 2):

$$\log_2 \left(\frac {18+x}x\right)=2$$
$$2^{\log_2 \left(\frac {18+x}x\right)}=2^2$$

use the property $$a^{\log_b c}=c^{\log_b a}$$

$$\left(\frac {18+x}x\right)^{\log_2 2}=4$$

$${\log_2 2}=1$$

$$\frac{18+x}{x}=4$$